# Create human verification for wordpress contact form with two random number

Tags: captcha

I have two number and an operator in three variables. For example $number1, $number2 and $operator. $operator contains only an operator from an array of (+, -, *, /). Now my question is how can I calculate mathematical operation with these three variables? For example 
$number1 ($operator) $number2 = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend you just stick to `*` and `+`, not expect people to deal with decimals and negative numbers. It is best to keep it simple as possible and not attempt to `eval` the string as an expression which is not good practice:

```
$operators = array('+', '*');
$operator = rand(0, 1);
$display = $number1.' '.$operators[$operator].' '.$number2;
if ($operators[$operator] == "*") {$result = $number1 * $number2;}
elseif ($operators[$operator] == "+") {$result = $number1 + $number2;}
```

Of course there are other ways to calculate without `eval`, [such as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071456/5240159), but probably not worth it unless you are doing something more complex.

Comment: no probs, I added some extra code for the random operator, if you like it you can mark the answer correct.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be done very simple, if I understand it correctly.

```
$operators = array( '+', '-', '*', '/' );
$key = rand( 0, 3 );
$result = $number1 . $operator[$key] . $number2;
```

I think the `. ' ' .` can also be replaced by just a `.` but I like 'spacious/clear' code.

Comment: cocatenation like this will just make the string like "3 * 6", which is fine for the display question, but not for performing the actual calculation.

Comment: I want to create a mathematical calculation using these two number and operator in the variable.

Comment: changed the concatenation.